# check the text of the drop down list is valid to open the next picker usnig Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift5, xcode12

### What I'm Using:

I'm using iOSDropDown Pod for showing list as a picker for any textField

---

### What I want to achieve :

I have two textfields one for ProfileType called profileTypeField and the other is category of that profileTypeField called cateoryField And there Class are of type IosDropDown! instead of UITextField! using the way of this pod I mentioned so what I want is:

### Explanation

if I selected a certain text like "Store" from profileTypeField using dropdown list of this pod
I want the user to select only the the category of that ProfileType On categoryField and show this Category text In Picker Or dropdownlist with the data of this Category in the categoryField

---

### my code that I've tried :

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    
    let option =  Options()
    profileTypeField.optionArray = option.profileTypes
    profileTypeField.optionIds = option.ids
    profileTypeField.checkMarkEnabled = true
    profileTypeField.isSearchEnable = false
    
    
    if (profileTypeField.selectedIndex == Int("Store")) {
        categoryField.optionArray = option.storeIndividualCategory
        categoryField.optionIds = option.ids
        categoryField.checkMarkEnabled = true
        categoryField.isSearchEnable = true
    }
    else if (profileTypeField.selectedIndex == Int("Service")) {
        categoryField.optionArray = option.serviceCategory
        categoryField.optionIds = option.ids
        categoryField.checkMarkEnabled = true
        categoryField.isSearchEnable = true
    }
    else {
        categoryField.optionArray = option.MediaCategory
        categoryField.optionIds = option.ids
        categoryField.checkMarkEnabled = true
        categoryField.isSearchEnable = false
    }
}
```

---

but it achieves only the first case of if statement and it doesn't perform the last of the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

profileTypeField.didSelect { (text, index, id) in

}

Inside this you can get the categories related to profile type assign them to categoryTextField.optionArray then enable  categoryTextField

Hope it helps.

Comment: can you provide more explanation by code pls!
ex: if I selected Media from profileTypeField -> show in categoryField list ["posts","likes","songs"]
also: if I selected Store from profileTypeField -> show in categoryField list ["ECommerce"] and so on and where can I put this profileTypeField.didSelect { (text, index, id) in
}
and what do you meen by enable categoryTextField!

Comment: How will you get the categories if you select "Store"?Do you have a web service?

Comment: categoryTextField.isEnabled = false

profileTypeField.didSelect { (text, index, id) in
    categoryTextField.isEnabled = true
    if text == "Media"{
        categorytextField.optionArray = ["posts","likes","songs"]
    }else{
        
    }
}

Comment: each profileType has it's own categories which are listed in categoryField depends on what I have chosen in profileTypeField

Comment: you can create a function then add this code and call the function from viewDidLoad.